# Should I delete an answer that was awarded a bounty if I feel it hasn't solved the original question?

Tags: discussion, bounty, etiquette

I recently answered a question here on Stack Overflow that was posted with a bounty ([High chart date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068910/high-chart-according-to-date)). The original poster commented on the answer with some follow-up questions, to which I responded, and, as needed, updated my answer accordingly.

The original poster awarded me the bounty, but continued to ask follow-up questions which required further communication and fine tuning of my answer. They also edited their question based on our discussions. After more back-and-forth in the comments, I believe I hit either a language barrier or a technology/skill barrier.

Regrettably, I don't what else I can do to help this person. I can neither directly replicate what they're attempting to do (due to an internal data source on their end), nor can I seem to get them to understand what I'm trying to tell them.

Since my answer is obviously not helpful to this person, and their problem remains unsolved, I don't want to keep the bounty. A moderator I consulted said bounties cannot be refunded.

What should I do here?

- **Should I delete my answer** so they can award the bounty to a more suitable answer?
- Also, to make sure I'm doing my part here on Stack Overflow, **was my final response to them in the answer comments clear and appropriate**?

As a side note, I realize I could have moved the extended comment chain to the chat section, and I will do so for future interactions like this.

Thank you, friends, for your guidance and advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear to me why the asker awarded the bounty to your answer if they felt your answer didn't address their problem to their satisfaction, especially considering *they still had nearly a full week ahead of them*. But that's their problem, not yours. If you don't wish to deal with them anymore, feel that your answer is not going to add any value to the question even for future readers, and don't want to keep the bounty, you may delete your answer. The bounty amount that was awarded will be removed from your profile, along with your earnings from upvotes.

To be clear (since you said "award *the* bounty to a more suitable answer"), the original bounty has been irrevocably attached to your answer. The asker can award a bounty to a more suitable answer in the future, but they need to start a new bounty for this. The 50 reputation they spent on the original one is gone forever. They're not getting it back, even if you delete your answer now. If you feel sorry for them, don't; it's not your fault they didn't use their bounty wisely.

Your final response to them was firm but composed. I'd say it's definitely appropriate given the situation. Even so, it seems the asker just isn't getting the hint that you're basically *done*. Your next best action is to not respond to them any further — you've already said all that you have had to say about the matter. I, on the other hand, have a valuable little piece of advice for them...

Comment: To no one's surprise, the user's response to my advice (in a now-deleted comment) was to change their mind and decide that your answer was helpful after all, and mark it accepted. Seems legit. If you *still* wish to delete the answer, flag it and I'll delete it for you. A user has freedom of choice when it comes to accepting an answer, but to do so for the sole purpose of locking it from deletion despite having stated clearly that it did not satisfy their requirements is in my books [abusive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/222314).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and thoughtful advice. I just read your link from the above comment and seem to have missed some of the back-and-forth between you and the original poster before their comments were deleted. With that loss of context, do you feel both the question I've posted and the "unique case" you cited merits keeping this around? I just want to do what's right.

Comment: @MikeZavarello correct - you can no longer self-delete. The question would have to be downvoted to a negative score and then have 3x20k+ users to cast delete votes to remove it (or - a moderator can remove it if warranted). If you feel the answer is still going to be of wider use to developers and you're happy to keep it and you're not being "harassed" any more, then I'd probably err on the side of keeping it. It'd be a shame to destroy something you've spent time on because of an over-enthusiastic question asker :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way the *system* can return the bounty. If you really don't feel you deserve the bounty, you can manually award an equally-sized bounty to one of the OP's [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102246/super-user?tab=answers). Yes, that would give a weird impression, a bounty on a zero-score answer, but it might help you with your feelings. Or give the bounty to some answer that was really helpful to you in the past.

Comment: This would smell fishy to observers, even if we deem this not to be a fraudulent reputation transfer between sock puppets or users in cahoots. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Even if @MikeZavarello feels that he doesn't deserve the bounty, the OP would have lost the reputation for the bounty anyway. So, IMHO, offering a bounty to one of the OP's answers in return seems to be a bit too much.